# Regarding use of cvStereorectify

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use cvstereorectify ([link](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereorectify)) to give me the Q matrix that I could then use back in cvReprojectImageto3D.
In the documentation of cvstereorectify though I am unsure how to get the R & T- The rotation matrix and the translation vector between the two cameras.Are there any methods that can help me do this? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [StereoCalibrate](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#StereoCalibrate)